# Extracting array of object from XML using SQL query

Tags: xml, database, oracle, stored-procedures, xpath

XML Data in a column Table:

```
<fundingBody>
   <contextName>Dell</contextName>
   <contextName>Hp</contextName> 
</fundingBody>
```

I need to store the array of `contextName` in my DB, so I have tried to fetch it using the following select query:

```
select extract(CONTENT,'/fundingBody/contextName/text()') from GWH_FUNDING_BODY  where ast_id=12112731;
```

Note: CONTENT is a column name, GWH_FUNDING_BODY is a table name

The result I'm getting is: `DellHp`

However the result I need is:`Dell;Hp`

What do I need to change to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

```
select extract(CONTENT,'/fundingBody/contextName/text()'),
';'
from GWH_FUNDING_BODY  where ast_id=12112731;
```

But this way you'll get a last one ; more. You can cut it out using substrings.

Comment: @Clasta : But it results in giving me two columns i) DellHp   ii) ;

Comment: The way you putted before, wasn't giving you two columns? i)Dell ii) Hp?
Because you can use something like:
select concat(extract(CONTENT,'/fundingBody/contextName/text()'), ';') from GWH_FUNDING_BODY where ast_id=12112731;
But you'll take a result like that:
i) Dell;
ii) Hp;

Comment: I tried, this gives me DellHp; .But the required result is Dell;Hp; or Dell;Hp

Comment: I'm sorry Krishna, but I have not how to test it here. So try to do:
select extract(concat(CONTENT,'/fundingBody/contextName/text()'), ';') from GWH_FUNDING_BODY where ast_id=12112731;

Comment: Reulting in : ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: I guess oracle could not do this